# Accept a string that can contain specific set + reject it if it contains specific word

Tags: javascript, java

I have a regular expression mentioned below.

```
(^[\s]*[0-9a-zA-Z\^\@\{\}\[\]\,\$\=\!\-\#\(\)\.\%\*\+\'\~\""\:\;\_\?]+[0-9a-zA-Z\^\@\{\}\[\]\,\$\=\!\-\#\(\)\.\%\*\+\'\~\""\:\;\_\?\s]*[0-9a-zA-Z\^\@\{\}\[\]\,\$\=\!\-\#\(\)\.\%\*\+\'\~\""\:\;\_\?]*[\s]*$)
```

I want to add one more condition in this regular expression that, it should reject the complete string if it contains word "java". I have tried many other example in this site but not able to get proper solution.

I am matching it with a string which is actually a paragraph i.e. it can contain newline character, tab and multiple spaces.

Comment: Why are you escaping everything? Only a very few characters have special meaning inside a `[ ]` character class. E.g. this will do: `[0-9a-zA-Z\^@{}\[\],$=!\-#().%*+'~":;_?]+`, and `^` doesn't even need escaping since it's not first.

Comment: @Andreas: I am very new to Regular expression. The regular expression that is in the description rejects &,<,>,| characters.

Comment: If you want regex for any [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) character other than space, `&`, `<`, `>`, or `|`, then you should use `[\p{Graph}&&[^&<>|]]`, i.e. a "visible character", but not one of `&<>|`

Comment: There are some very good online regex testers, which will not only test your regex but also explain the composition of the regex and also show you step by step the matching. I recommend that you try them.

Answer (score 1):

Add `(?!X)` [zero-width negative lookahead](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special) to the beginning.

If you don't know what the existing regex is, wrap it in a non-capturing group, otherwise a top-level `|` (OR) will break it.

```
String newRegex = "(?!(?s:.*?)java)(?:" + oldRegex + ")";
```

Comment: Above does not work for me. I have a multiline string like "abcd \n abcd java \n abcd"

Comment: @Pragya The `.` wasn't matching line terminators. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply, but with the current regex is throwing invalid regular expersion for the second '?'

Comment: @Pragya No idea what you are talking about. I copy/pasted the regex from the question, and it works, with and without the addition of the regex in the answer. Perhaps you didn't correctly escape all the quotes and escapes when you made the regex into a Java string literal. If you have trouble with that, and want help, you need to create a new question asking about that, showing the plain regex as you have it here, and showing the Java string literal you created from it.